# Javascript functions are not working in IE11

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, silverlight, internet-explorer

We are using an app which is designed in MVC and Silverlight. That app is working fine in IE10. But we are not able to run the app in IE11. We have set of javascript functions with is used to do validation on our app. Those functions are not at all working. I am getting 'undefined' error. Even i have tried with `<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=10">` also. If any one can help me, you are my Savior.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Could you show those functions? It's a bit hard to tell why they are not working without you showing them.

Answer (score 3):

Also note some detection fixes:  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2836939/en-us

More details (for older OS's and .NET versions)

KBs for the IE11 GDR:

- 2836939 .NET 4 - Win7SP1/Win2K3SP2/Win2K8R2SP1/Win2K8SP2/VistaSP2/WinXPSP3
- 2836940 .NET 3.5 SP1 - Win2K3SP2/Win2K8SP2/VistaSP2/WinXPSP3
- 2836941 .NET 2.0 SP2 - Win2K3SP2/WinXPSP3
- 2836942 .NET 3.5 SP1 - Win7SP1/Win2K8R2SP1
- 2836943 .NET 2.0 SP2 - Win7SP1/Win2K8R2SP1
- 2836945 .NET 2.0 SP2 - Win2K8SP2/VistaSP2
- 2836946 .NET 2.0 SP2 - Win8RTM/WinRTRTM/Win2K12RTM
- 2836947 .NET 3.5 SP1 - Win8RTM/WinRTRTM/Win2K12RTM

Answer (score 1):

Add localhost to compatibility setting in IE 11.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing browser detection or x-ua-compatible, you should not be. There is no guarantee that either of these methods will work in the future.

.NET Browser Definitions will not detect IE11 as Internet Explorer, resulting in the "...undefined" errors.

You should instead use feature detection to determine features supported by the browser.

In a pinch, the only official method (per the IE11 Compatibility Changes guide on Microsoft's site) for detecting IE11 is to check for the "Trident" token in the User Agent.

Answer (score 0):

I had tried all the hotfixes which described the issue. "Script Error encountered", "'__doPostBack' is undefined" but only solution that worked for me was .NET 4.5 . You can read more about my findings in these questions [CrossPostback ,AJAX Controls and ASP.NET generated postbacks work for .NET 4.5 , not .NET 4.0 in IE 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18009636/crosspostback-ajax-controls-and-asp-net-generated-postbacks-work-for-net-4-5?noredirect=1#comment27966770_18009636) and [WebResource.axd not working with Internet Explorer 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17861424/webresource-axd-not-working-with-internet-explorer-11)