# WebResource.axd not working with Internet Explorer 11

Tags: .net, internet-explorer, iis, webresource.axd, windows-8.1

We're testing our websites for the new Windows 8.1 IE 11 browsers classic and metro. 
There is a `Javascript` file embedded in `WebResource.axd`.
The `WebResource` is generated and loaded fine with Firefox,Google Chrome and IE 11 with the site added in Compatibility View.
The only issue is IE 11 both classic and metro where the `WebResource` is not loaded. 
I am not seeking a precise answer but what confuses me is , 
I can't see the `WebResource` `<script>` tag in the generated HTML. Neither can I see any request made for the resource which is kind of implicit.
Now my question is where could be the issue , I debugged my code and couldn't find it failing in any of the custom handlers or modules.
 Is it failing in IIS handlers (AssemblyResourceLoader-Integrated) or at the generation logic where you register the `WebResource`?

Comment: Could be related to the [problems with IE10](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BugAndFixASPNETFailsToDetectIE10CausingDoPostBackIsUndefinedJavaScriptErrorOrMaintainFF5ScrollbarPosition.aspx). Try setting `Page.ClientTarget = "uplevel"` in the `Page_Init` event.

Comment: oh ok .. I'll try and let u know .. rite now I can't access the remote machine.

Comment: oh ok .. Thanks... I fail to understand how Microsoft ported a new O/S and not include this fix with it ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Richard's workaround above:

> Setting `Page.ClientTarget = "uplevel"` in the `Page_Init` event.

is the correct one; you need to disable the use of User-Agent sniffing to get ASPNET to send IE11 the proper script blocks. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.clienttarget.aspx

Unfortunately, it turns out that the patch they took to enable IE10 doesn't work properly with IE11 (because the IE team significantly changed the IE user agent string, removing the MSIE token by default). So, another patch for ASP.NET was shipped in June 2013. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/18651133/126229

Comment: Thanks Richard ... I still have to try... will surely confirm you the result ... Plus I think you're correct about the user agent string. I find some CSS work had to be done again for gradients and so on.

Comment: @All , I downloaded the IE 11 for Win 7 and pointed to code on my machine means my machine became the client and server and everything worked. FYI I haven't explicitly installed any hotfix or changed anything at the PageLevel. Infact I couldn't install the hotfix as I have VS 2012. I assumed the IE 11 for Win 7 had to do with this. But if I point the server to the original QA machine , the issue is still there. So the hotfix has either come with .NET 4.5 or one of my Installed updates.

Comment: When you visit a page on your Intranet/local machine, by default the page is loading in IE's "Compatibility View" mode which uses the IE7 User-Agent string (and thus avoids the ASP.NET issue). You can see this by hitting F12 and looking at the "Browser Mode" indicator.

Comment: The IE 11 Developer tool hasn't ported the Browser Indicator mode. I'll be trying out pointing other clients using Win 8.1 to point my machine as the server.

Comment: I used a different client and directed the server to my machine and everything still works. The question remain as to how is it working in my machine , has .NET 4.5 anything to do with it or some  other installed updates.

Comment: .NET 4.5 resolves the issue. As a workaround above is the solution but changing the client. Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18009636/crosspostback-ajax-controls-and-asp-net-generated-postbacks-work-for-net-4-5

Answer (score 1):

We were finally able to resolve the issue by installing the hotfix http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2600088 (32bit or 64 bit) mentioned by Richard and more then run the `aspnet_regbrowsers -i` .
Thanks all for the solutions. Didn't want to take the claim for the answer but maybe people might not find it in comments.

Comment: This is not the answer. Answer is .NET 4.5 resolves the issue. As a workaround above is the solution. Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18009636/crosspostback-ajax-controls-and-asp-net-generated-postbacks-work-for-net-4-5