# Microsoft reporting services crashes when trying to print from internet explorer 11

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I just upgraded my browser to IE 11 and everytime I try to print a report from reporting services, the browser stops working and crashes. For some of our users, the print button is even disabled.

Is anyone else having this problem and does anyone know of a fix? Thanks.

Comment: Please check if it's not switch to compatibility mode, also if there are any js errors  while loading.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely SSRS is running ASP.Net 4.0 which has issues with browser sniffing IE 11. So you have a few options, The "easiest" being upgrade to .Net 4.5.

You could also follow the steps here if that is not an option for you.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/19855256/3096369
That would allow ASP.Net to successfully sniff IE 11.

Comment: How can you tell which version ssrs is running?

Comment: I don't think it's the SSRS version. SSRS is basically a .Net web application. It looks like SSRS runs on .Net 2.0 [link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2869522/en-us) so you're best option is going to be update your Config\Browsers files to sniff IE11 correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Let me guess, you are SQL Server R2 without SP2. I had to upgrade to Sql Server 2008 R2 SERVICE PACK 2.

> The version of RsClientPrint you get with R2/SP2 is 10.50.4000, while
>   the version I had was 10.50.1600.

[ReportViewer's Print Button Incompatible with IE 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17031060/reportviewers-print-button-incompatible-with-ie-10)